# JQuery and AJAX, retrive a variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm starting with jQuery and AJAX and trying to pass a value from page 2 to page 1 but this script I have did not work

**Script:**

```
function prova()
    {
    var parametro = $("#nome_privato").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "./ProvaAJAX.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "parametro="+parametro,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( response )
        {
            alert(response);
        },
        //error: function (){}
        });
    }
```

**select:**

```
    <select onChange='prova()'>
<input type='text' id='nome_privato'>
```

**"./ProvaAJAX.php":**

```
<?php
    $_GET['parametro'];
    echo "il parametro è".$_GET['parametro'] ;
?>
```

i think could bee a syntax error too because javascript get disabled in other parts of my page...

Comment: `$("nome_privato").val();` is wrong. Add a `.` for a class or `#` for an id. Also you need a selector for your `<select>`.

Comment: changed in var parametro = $("#nome_privato").val(); but still not work

Comment: Well it won't if you didn't add an id to your select.

Comment: url not work in crosss domain so please check "./ProvaAJAX.php" file existing or not then try it again

Comment: It's obviously not cross-domain, since he's using a relative path.

Comment: Please tell me that's a short example of your `<select>` tag, and not how you're actually using it.

Comment: can you please check my below example  [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589265/jquery-and-ajax-retrive-a-variable/18589511#18589511)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
data: "parametro="+parametro,
```

to:

```
data: {'parametro': parametro},
```

You also don't need the `$_GET['parametro'];` line in your php script, just the echo line.

---

Not a big issue in newer browsers but you should also remove the trailing comma on this:

```
    success: function( response )
    {
        alert(response);
    },
```

**Edit**

See Ben's answer, I'm blind.

Comment: thanks for the reply but still doesn't work...
i deleted $_GET['parametro']; too

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
function prova()
    {
    var parametro = $("#selectid").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "./ProvaAJAX.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: "parametro="+parametro,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( response )
        {
            alert(response);
        },
        //error: function (){}
        });
    }
```

HTML

```
<select id="selectid" onChange='prova()'>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    echo "il parametro è".$_GET['parametro'] ;
?>
```

You weren't using your selector properly.

Comment: IE generally doesn't like trailing spaces on object literals, but otherwise this seems to address the issues with it. Some words explaining what you've changed and why it's necessary would really go a long way though.

Comment: "nome_privato" is another filed, is an input text box, sorry for my wrong explanation

Comment: @Jacopo The selector is still wrong, since `$("nome_privato")` is looking for an element created with a `<nome_privato>` tag (which you'll recognise as not being an actual HTML tag).

Comment: yes, i have yet changed to: var parametro = $("#nome_privato").val() as suggest by @Ben Fortune

Comment: But you've just said that you're using it for another field. Choose a unique id and selector.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this selector val :

```
<select onChange='prova()' id="nome_privato">
```

There are misstack in getting value from var parametro = $("nome_privato").val();
used this

$("#nome_privato").val();

```
function prova()
{
var parametro = $("#nome_privato").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "ProvaAJAX.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: "parametro="+parametro,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function( response )
    {
        alert(response);
    },
    //error: function (){}
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

data option for the Ajax call should be an object to be translated to the proper GET parameter, i.e. `data: {parametro: $("nome_privato").val()}`